# access uino variable when union name is not defined

Tags: c, struct, esp32, i2c, arduino-esp32

I am working with esp32 and trying to use the i2c library.

There is a config struct.

```
typedef struct{
i2c_mode_t mode;     /*!< I2C mode */
int sda_io_num;      /*!< GPIO number for I2C sda signal */
int scl_io_num;      /*!< GPIO number for I2C scl signal */
bool sda_pullup_en;  /*!< Internal GPIO pull mode for I2C sda signal*/
bool scl_pullup_en;  /*!< Internal GPIO pull mode for I2C scl signal*/

union {
    struct {
        uint32_t clk_speed;     /*!< I2C clock frequency for master mode, (no higher than 1MHz for now) */
    } master;
    struct {
        uint8_t addr_10bit_en;  /*!< I2C 10bit address mode enable for slave mode */
        uint16_t slave_addr;    /*!< I2C address for slave mode */
    } slave;
};
} i2c_config_t;
```

From this when i try to create and assign in my code the i2c_config_t like:

```
                i2c_config_t i2cConfigT={
                    .mode = I2C_MODE_MASTER,
                    .sda_io_num = _sda,
                    .scl_io_num = _clk,
                    .sda_pullup_en = GPIO_PULLUP_ENABLE,
                    .scl_pullup_en = GPIO_PULLUP_ENABLE,
                    .master.clk_speed = 100000};
```

i get error on last row at the . before the master variable.

Error says

> expected primary-expression before '.' token

From this i see that there is no defined name for the union is it possible this to be the issue?

Comment: What are you using to compile this code? With gcc 11.1.1 it seems to compile without any errors.

Comment: "cStandard": "c11","cppStandard": "c++17", but it is xtensa-esp32-elf compiler from esp-idf framework. it is esp32 project

Comment: try giving the `union` a name within `i2c_config_t` , say for example `options` and initialize with  `.options.master.clk_speed = 100000`   But do you really need the union?  you could just make `master` and `slave` as `struct`s within `i2c_config_t` without a huge space hit.

Comment: @infixed, the struct is part of library API

Comment: Where is that error? Which dot does expect the primary-expression ?

Comment: The code seems ok, but please do post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.master = {
  .clk_speed = 100000,
}
```